# Having trouble displaying results correctly after changing the value of an Ace from 11 to 1 in a blackjack simulation

Tags: javascript

This is the first time I've written anything beyond a few simple lines in javascript. I know similar questions have been asked before because I've looked at a lot of them. I still can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong though. I am attempting to make a blackjack game simulation. I've almost got it except I keep running into problems when I need to change the value of an ace from 11 to 1. When I need to change the value of an ace from 11 to 1, it seems to only display the last player's results. Here's the script in it's entirety:

```
function cardShuffle(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
function contains(arr, obj) {
    var i = 0;
    for (;i < arr.length;i++) {
        if (arr[i] === obj) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
function blackjack() {
    var spades = "\u2660";
    var clubs = "\u2663";
    var hearts = "\u2665";
    var diamonds = "\u2666";
    var dealer = "Dealer";
    var player = "Player";
    var table = [player, dealer];
    var suits = [hearts, clubs, diamonds, spades];
    var deck = [];
    // create a deck of cards
    x = 0;
    for (;x < suits.length; x++) {
        var cards = ["A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K"];
        i = 0;
        for (;i < cards.length; i++) {
            deck.push(cards[i] + suits[x]);
        }
    }
    i = 0;
    for (;i < table.length; i++) {
        var players = table[i];
        var cardsToDeal = 1;
        var cardsHeld = [];
        var sum = [];
        aces = [];
        var result;
        for (;0 < cardsToDeal;) {
            // get a random card from the deck
            var index = cardShuffle(0, deck.length - 1);
            var card = deck[index];
            // give the card to the player
            cardsHeld.push(card);
            // remove the card from the deck
            deck.splice(index, 1);
            // strip the suit from the card and get the value
            var value = card.substring(0, card.length - 1);
            if (value == "J" || (value == "Q" || value == "K")) {
                value = 10;
            } else {
                if (value == "A") {
                    value = 11;
                    // put aces into a separate array 
                    aces.push(value);
                } else {
                    value = Number(value);
                }
            }
            // put the value of the card into the sum array
            sum.push(value);
            // store the sum of the value in the total variable
            var total = sum.reduce(add, 0);
            /*
            This is where I think the problem is. 
            It works if the last player's hand is greater than 21 and contains an ace. 
            But if the first players hand has an ace and is greater than 21 
            only those result are shown in console.log. I don't know why.
            */
            if (total > 21 && contains(sum, 11)) {
                var i = sum.indexOf(11);
                if (i !== -1) {
                    sum[i] = 1;
                }
                total = sum.reduce(add, 0);
            }
            if (total >= 17 && total <= 21) {
                result = Number(total);
            }
            if (total >= 17) {
                cardsToDeal--;
            }
        }
        console.log(players, cardsHeld, sum, total);
    }
}
blackjack();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line:

```
for (;i < table.length; i++) {
```

... you use a variable `i` for a loop. But inside this loop, you redefine that variable, and change its value:

```
var i = sum.indexOf(11);
```

which results in this kind of behavior:

[image]

If you just change that variable's name to something else, it seems to work fine:

```
if (total > 21 && contains(sum, 11)) {
    var index = sum.indexOf(11);
    if (index !== -1) {
        sum[index] = 1;
    }
    total = sum.reduce(add, 0);
}
```

Be careful about variable scopes when using the `var` keyword, they are not limited to blocks -unlike `let`- but to functions (and be sure to add a `var` in front of the first definition, to avoid making it global). Also, just a piece of advice. `for` loops are generally used when you know how many iterations you're going to do. This:

```
for (;0 < cardsToDeal;) { /*...*/ }
```

would be better with a `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

When you check for Aces, you declare `i` again. This changes the value of `i` in your table loop. Change the the second `var i` to `var ii` and you should be good. To better understand this, you can look up more about Javascript [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

```
if (total > 21 && contains(sum, 11)) {
   var ii = sum.indexOf(11); // This is what changed
   if (ii !== -1) {
      sum[ii] = 1;
   }
   total = sum.reduce(add, 0);
}
```